# How to set daily google app script to output fixed value

Tags: google-apps-script

Am quite new with Google Scripts and wondering if anyone can help with this.

I've connected Google Analytics to Google Sheets (via add-on) and made settings so that conversion numbers are generated daily into a new google sheet tab (sheetB).

I'd like to match dates then copy the conversion data from sheetB to sheetA (master sheet which has acts like a dashboard).

The above can be done using this formula:
=IF(DA2=JuicerSessTime!$A$16,JuicerSessTime!$B$16)

The problem I'm facing is that since the above is a formula, I can't save the conversion data as a fixed value. So yesterday's value would show as FALSE from the formula above.

I'd like to be able to keep and save all daily generated values.

I've tried to create a google script below but it doesn't seem to work, hope someone can help.

```
function moveOneValuesOnlyToday() {
  var mydate = new Date();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sdate = ss.getRange('sheetB!B2');
  var sdate2 = ss.getRange('sheetA!DA2');
  var source = ss.getRange('sheetA!DA5');

  if (sdate == sdate2){
     source.copyTo(ss.getRange('sheetA!DA6'), {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are comparing ranges instead of values. Use getValue() right after getRange().

Comment: Thanks @Sergeinsas!